# planar Poisson line process & angles of inclination

Tags: poisson-process, simulation, geometric-probability

Let $L_j$ denote the lines of a planar Poisson line process.  By Example 20 of

http://staffhome.ecm.uwa.edu.au/~00025879/reprints/chapter1-abstract.html
http://staffhome.ecm.uwa.edu.au/~00025879/reprints/chapter1.ps

inclination angles $\omega_{j}$ of the lines $L_j$ relative to the $x$-axis are independent and identically distributed with density $\sin(\omega)/2$ on
$[0,\pi]$. In particular, the vertical lines are weighted more than
horizontal lines.

The R package *spatstat* has planar random process
simulation capabilities.  I can generate Poisson lines in a window via
*rpoisline* and determine their inclination angles $\omega_{j}$ via
*angles.psp* (with option *directed=FALSE*). To avoid edge
effects, I restrict attention to only those lines fairly close to the window
center. Surprisingly, the angles seem to follow not the sine density, but
instead the uniform density on $[0,\pi]$.

What am I missing please?  I would be grateful for help, e.g., R, Matlab or Mathematica code giving experimental results that match theoretical prediction.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code shows the paradox mentioned by @adrian-baddeley
experimentally. In a circular sampling window we see a nearly uniform
distribution of angles:

```
library(spatstat)
X  <- rpoisline(400, win = disc())
aa <- angles.psp(X)
plot(density(aa))
```

[image]

In a long thin sampling window we see a nearly sinusodial distribution
of angles:

```
X  <- rpoisline(1000, win = owin(c(0,10), c(0,.01)))
aa <- angles.psp(X)
plot(density(aa))
plot(function(x){0.5*sin(x)},from=0,to=pi,add=TRUE,col="red")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this elegant solution.  Your technique of making the window "line-like" is certainly effective & helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic paradox.

If you consider the random lines which **intersect a given, fixed line**, then these random lines have angles which are non-uniformly distributed with probability density proportional to the sine of the incidence angle. If you consider the random lines which **intersect a given circle** then these random lines have uniformly-distributed orientation angles. In each case the **bold text** describes a selection or sampling operation, and sampling operations introduce bias.

Comment: Thank you for writing!

The theorem is indeed paradoxical.  I am trying unsuccessfully to confirm this experimentally using "rpoisline" & "angles.psp".  Are you able to successfully do this?

I appreciate deeply the chance to correspond with you.